# Query Count of Specific Event Action in Piwik

Tags: php, matomo

I need to make a widget/plugin for my organization using Piwik but I'm a little lost. We send custom events to Piwik such as:

```
Category: Staff 
Action: Login
```

How would i query piwik from within a widget/plugin to get the # of events that match that particular category/action?

Comment: I've refined my answer to match better what you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the documentation regarding the [Events API](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api#Events).

There are 2 methods that might interest you:

- `Events.getCategory`
- `Events.getAction`

They will return a list of actions/categories mapped to `nb_uniq_visitors`, `nb_visits` and `nb_events`.

The `nb_events` might be the one that you should use to get the number of events for each category or action. Here is an example of query for the event category list:

http://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=Events.getCategory&idSite=7&period=day&date=today&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous

Note that you don't especially need to write a Piwik plugin for that, you just need to query the [Reporting API](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/reporting-introduction). However if you want to display those numbers in Piwik then indeed you'll need to write a plugin.

---

**Edit:** you want to know how to get that list from within a custom Piwik plugin.

Have a look at the [Calling APIs of other plugins](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/expose-api-methods#calling-apis-of-other-plugins) documentation. In your case you would have to call the Events API like this:

```
$table = \Piwik\API\Request::processRequest('Events.getCategory', array(
    'idSite' => $idSite,
    'period' => $period,
    'date'   => $date,
));
```

Once you have the table, you can find the row that interest you:

```
$row = $table->getRowFromLabel('Staff');
```

Then get the number of events in the period:

```
$numberOfEvents = $row->getColumn('nb_events');
```

Note that you can also optimize your call to the API to filter and get only the label you are searching, and the column you are using:

```
$table = \Piwik\API\Request::processRequest('Events.getCategory', array(
    'idSite'      => $idSite,
    'period'      => $period,
    'date'        => $date,
    'label'       => 'Staff',
    'showColumns' => 'nb_events',
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the really in-depth explanation!